# How to specify absolute path to Dockerfile on docker build

Tags: dockerfile, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

How can I specify -t and -f parameters on docker cloud build job.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |-
          docker build --network=cloudbuild -f pipeline/components/testdocker/Dockerfile  -t europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/xxx/test .

  dir: 'mc2-AIBooster_POC/'
```

I get the following error: "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument"

Comment: There is a different approach in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers#use-buildconfig). Can you elaborate why are you doing it this way? Try to open the dir with your `Dockerfile` and print its `pwd` and follow the docs I linked. See if it helps.

Comment: I need to specify 2 commands, that`s why I do it my way. 
the problem is that I need to tag the image with -t and then change the DOckerfile directory with -f 
The error I get is  "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument

Comment: Can you provide your `cloudbuild.yaml` file?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding a dot to your command? E.g. `docker build --network=cloudbuild -t europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/image-name -f pipeline/components/testdocker . `

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add a dot at the end of you `docker build` command, the order of flags shouldn't matter:

```
docker build --network=cloudbuild -t europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/vf-grp-aib-dev-buildnl/docker-repository/$_PROJECT_ID/$_USER/$_BRANCH/test -f pipeline/components/testdocker/Dockerfile .
```

More about using `docker build` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Answer (score 3):

By using -f first and then -t .

Make sure to add a dot at the end of your command

```
docker build --network=cloudbuild -f pipeline/components/testdocker/Dockerfile -t europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/vf-grp-aib-dev-buildnl/docker-repository/$_PROJECT_ID/$_USER/$_BRANCH/test .
```